# Can I GROUP BY in MySQL, but have it ignore null values when grouping, dropping a result row if necessary?

Tags: mysql, group-by, left-join

My tables:

t1

```
col_a  col_b
1       100    
1       200
1       300
2       400
```

t2

```
col_a  col_b
100      5
100      6
```

t3

```
col_a  col_b
5       100
6       200
6       300
```

If I run a query and left join the 3 tables in order i get:

```
1   100  5     100
1   100  6     200
1   100  6     300
1   200  null  null
1   300  null  null
2   400  null  null
```

If I add group by t1.col_a, t2.col_b:

```
1   100           5      100
1   100           6      (200 or 300)
1   (200 or 300)  null   null
2   400           null   null
```

But I don't want to the 3rd row to show because it does not have a value in t2.col_b. I could add a condition to where that column is not null, but that would remove the last row which needs to stay.

In a perfect query I would like to see:

```
1   100           5      100
1   100           6      (200 or 300)
2   400           null   null
```

Comment: Why you don't want the 3rd row, but the last row. Both rows don't have a relation to t2. It's impossible to remove one row and get the other, if you don't have a rule.

Comment: basically the first table represents a user, the second is a property of the user, the third is a property of the property. i want all the users to show, whether or not they have any properties assigned - which is why the last line has to stay. i don't want that third line to show because i already have two rows for that user. i realize there is information in the second result column that is unique, but i really only care about duplicating user rows when the third table is unique.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one. t1.col_b is a little tricky, because if multiple t1.col_a values exists with none reference to t2, this query select a random for this.

```
SELECT
    sub.col_a,
    IFNULL(sub.relation,t1.col_b),
    t2.col_b,
    t3.col_b
FROM(
    SELECT 
        t1.col_a,
        group_concat(DISTINCT t2.col_a) AS relation 
    FROM table1 AS t1
    LEFT JOIN table2 AS t2 ON t2.col_a = t1.col_b
    GROUP BY t1.col_a
) AS sub
LEFT JOIN table1 AS t1
    ON t1.col_a = sub.col_a
    AND (t1.col_b IN (sub.relation) OR sub.relation IS NULL)
LEFT JOIN table2 AS t2
    ON t2.col_a = t1.col_b
LEFT JOIN table3 AS t3
    ON t3.col_a = t2.col_b
GROUP BY t1.col_a, t2.col_b
```

Answer (score 0):

One approach is to select only the non-null rows as a part of the result, then union it with a broader - but grouped - set of results:

```
SELECT * FROM t1
 JOIN t2 ON t1.col_b = t2.col_a
 LEFT JOIN t3 ON t2.col_b = t3.col_a

UNION

SELECT * FROM t1
  LEFT JOIN t2 ON t1.col_b = t2.col_a
  LEFT JOIN t3 ON t2.col_b = t3.col_a
GROUP BY t1.col_a
```

Notice that the first query does not have a LEFT JOIN. That's because we don't want any NULL results in that query. That query gives you:

```
t1.col_a    t2.col_a    t3.col_a    t3.col_b
   1           100          5         100
   1           100          6         200
   1           100          6         300
```

And the second query gives you:

```
t1.col_a    t2.col_a    t3.col_a    t3.col_b
   1           100          5         100
   2           400         NULL       NULL
```

Finally, when you do a UNION, it gets rid of the duplicate result (first row in first result set is equal to the first row in the second result set).  This is the default behavior of the [UNION command](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/union.html), resulting in:

```
t1.col_a    t2.col_a    t3.col_a    t3.col_b
   1           100          5         100
   1           100          6         200
   1           100          6         300
   2           400         NULL       NULL
```